# htmlpurifier with css3 linear-gradient support?

Tags: htmlpurifier

I have extent htmlpurifier 4.7.0 with major (for my custom case) html5 and css3 support. Most taken from examples overall on web and sources of mahara project. Unfortunately, I still lack support for "linear-gradient".

Does anyone know of a source for linear-gradient support in htmlpurifier?